# How to call a function and pass arguments to it in x86 assembly

Tags: c++, c, function, assembly, x86

Intel CPU
Windows 10 64bit
C++
x86 assembly

I have two programs, both written by me in C++. For the sake of simplicity I will refer to them as program A and program B. They do not do anything special really, I am just using them to test things out and have some fun in the process.

The idea is that program A injects code into program B and that injected code will set the parameters of a function in program B and will call a function in program B.

I must say I have learned a lot from this experiment. As I needed to open up a handle to a process with proper permissions and then construct assembly code to inject, call it with CreateRemoteThread and clean up afterwards.

I ve managed to do this and call a function from program B and that function takes one parameter of type UINT64.

I do this by injecting the following assembly code:

```
b9 paramAddr
e8 funcAddr
c3
```

By calling this code snippet from program A with CreateRemoteThread in program B I manage to call a function at an address and with a parameter passed. And this works fine. Nothing too complex just call a function that takes one param. One thing to note here is that I have injected the parameter prior to this code and just provided a parameter address to b9.

Now what I am failing to do is call a function in program B from program A that takes two parameters.

Function Example: 
myFunction(uint num1, int num2)

The procedure for injection is the same, and all that works just fine windows API provides plenty of well documented functionalities.

What I do not seam to be able to do is pass the two parameters to the function. This is where my troubles begin. I have been looking at x86 assembly function call conventions. And what they do is either just

```
push param2
push param1
call functAddr
retn
```

or

perform a mov to esi

Could anyone please clarify,explain and provide a clear example of how to call a function in x86 assembly that takes two parameters or type uint and int.

Thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: On x86-64 some args are passed in registers others on the stack. Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: First parameter is in `rcx`, second in `rdx` (then `r8` and `r9`). You also need to create an [home area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-allocation), possibly via a `sub rsp, 20h`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Depends on the calling convention...

Comment: @Macmade Yes. Windows 64 bit C++ code, compiled with VC++, used this calling convention last time I checked.

Comment: @MargaretBloom : Yep x86-64 has pretty much standardized to that one convention on Windows.

Comment: If program A isn't a debugger it has no business using `CreateRemoteThread`. That that API even _exists_ is a strong contender for the biggest single design mistake in Windows.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin How do I determine if my function requires args to be passes in registers or on the stack?

Comment: @ChronicUser its simply the amount of arguments. The first four always go in `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8` and `r9` (in 64-bit Windows anyway..). The rest are placed on the stack AFTER the shadow/home/scratch space. Basically, if you've got 6 args you're passing, arg 5 would go to `[rsp+0x28]` and arg 6 would go to `[rsp+0x30]` ... etc (this takes into account the return address already present on the stack ... you would need to adjust it if you are setting up another local frame).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a way to understand and clarify what is happening internally, I recommend to start with generating an assembler file for the specific machine you are working with. If you are using gcc or g++ you can use the `-S` flag to generate the associated assembler files. For the beginning you can implement a function with two arguments and call that function inside your main function. Using the assembler files, you should get a really good picture of how the stack is filled before your function is called and where your return value is put. In the next step you should compare what you see in the assembler file with the [x86 calling convetion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: ABI is also related to the OS, not only the machine.

Comment: @Macmade Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the instructions. I went over the assembly code of the function a few more times. The simple problem was the fact that you must determine the order of the arguments and then pass them in a reverse order. Furthermore you must see what arguments go to the stack and which ones will go into to the registries.